# C++ clear vector of structs exception

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I defined a struct called Part:

```
struct Part
{
    std::string id;
    double area;
    double volume;

    bool operator==(const Part& part) const
    {
        return (area == part.area) && (volume == part.volume);
    }

    bool operator!=(const Part& part) const
    {
        return !operator==(part);
    }

    bool operator<(const Part &part) const
    {
        return (area + volume) < part.area + part.volume;
    }
};
```

I created a vector of Parts and saved the vector in a binary file.
Then I read the binary file into a vector. I confirmed that all Parts are correctly read into the vector. My function to read binary file is:

```
static bool restore_vector_from_file(const char* fileName, std::vector<Part> &parts) {

    std::ifstream instream(fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if (!instream) {
        return false;
    }

    instream.seekg(0, instream.end);
    int bytes = instream.tellg();
    instream.seekg(0, instream.beg);

    int vector_size = bytes / sizeof(Part);
    parts.resize(vector_size);
    instream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(parts.data()), bytes);

    if (!instream) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    instream.close();
    return true;
}
```

My main function is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Number of arguments must be 3" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Load parts with properties to a vector
    const char* folderName = argv[1];
    const char* vectorFileName = argv[2];

    std::vector<Part> partArray;

    // Load from pre-saved file to save time
    if (!restore_vector_from_file(vectorFileName, partArray))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to retore vector from file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    partArray.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine until I try to clear `partArray`. It throws an exception:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0x1BC586CCB48.
```

Even if I remove `partArray.clear()`, the same exception is thrown when `return 0;`

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Your structure `Part` is not a [POD type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) and not [trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialType), therefore you can't save or load it like you do.

Take its `id` member, a `std::string` object usually contains a *pointer* which is what is saved. That pointer will not be valid in any other process.

You need to use [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) to save and load your structure.

Comment: Being `POD` or `trivial` doesn't really mean anything here. You can easily construct a POD type which couldn't be (de)serialized in the same way. I.e. `struct Foo { int *bar; };` Btw, worth mentioning that "pod" definition is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

```
instream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(parts.data()), bytes);
```

That's a big code smell and UB as well. `std::string` holds a pointer to heap allocated string (modulo SSO), but when you try to reinterpret_cast it form file (assuming you saved it the same way) you'll just get some garbage value (since it now doesn't point to any valid memory location), so when the `std::string` tries to deallocate it in the destructor it'll fail like you've experienced. You simply can't do what you are trying to do here.

I suggest you overload `istream& operator>> (istream& is, Part& p);` for your struct. And the corresponding `<<` for ostream as well. It should be easy since such overloads already exists for all `Part` fields.